# Help with multiline regex match

Tags: python, xml, regex

I am trying to have a regular expression match a value that spans multiple lines. I am using the re.S flag, but still get no results. Any ideas why?

This is the text that I am searching through:

```
<File id="abc.txt" EngRev="74">
  <Identifier id="STRING_ID" isArray="1" goesWith="3027253">
    <EngTranslation>"Value 1","Value 2","Value 3","Value 4","Value 5",</EngTranslation>
    <LangTranslation filename="abc.txt" key="STRING_ID 0">Value 1</LangTranslation>
    <array filename="abc.txt" key="STRING_ID 1">Value 2</array>
    <array filename="abc.txt" key="STRING_ID 2">Value 3</array>
    <array filename="abc.txt" key="STRING_ID 3">Value 4</array>
    <array filename="abc.txt" key="STRING_ID 4">Value 5</array>
  </Identifier>
  <Identifier id="STRING_ID2" isArray="0" goesWith="3027253">
    <EngTranslation>"Value 1"</EngTranslation>
    <LangTranslation filename="abc.txt" key="STRING_ID2">Value 1</LangTranslation>
  </Identifier>
</File>
```

This is the code I am using to obtain a match:

```
def updateToArray(matchobj):
     return matchobj.group(0).replace('LangTranslation','array')
outXML = re.sub(r'<Identifier.*?<array.*?</Identifier>', updateToArray, outXML, re.S)
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Don't use a regex to parse XML.  Use an XML library.

Answer (score 7):

I strongly urge you to not use regular expressions for parsing XML. SO has a [lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494079/how-can-i-find-tag-with-regular-expression-python/3494127#3494127) question/answer threads explaining why. For instance see [this classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Since you are using Python why not use libraries like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [Lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) to do the job much more cleanly and concisely?

Comment: I'm only 7 days active at SO. But have noticed there's approximately one question per day about parsing XML or HTML by RE. It should be captured somewhere as common antipattern.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an argument:

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string[, count, flags])
```

The flags appear to be integers, so it's treating `re.S` as the `count` argument.  Using zero for `count` preserves the default behavior and allows you to pass the flags as the fifth argument.